# SUBSCRIBE Response using SIP-Sorcery C#

Tags: c#, sip

I'm trying to use the sip sorcery from codeplex, in a C# SIP client project, to send and receive requests and responses to my server. When I use the SIPUDPChannel.Send('remoteEP', 'msg'), I can see that a SUBSCRIBE packet is send to my server, and that my server answering with a status response.

But how does I catch response/request events with the SIP Sorcery API???

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code.

Comment: I figured out how to receive responses. Here's a snippet http://pastebin.com/pNqLYpc7

But, I'm having another issue now (ofcause). When I'm sending a new channel.Send() inside the Transport_SIPTransportResponseReceived(), I can see that it is sending in-dialog which it shouldn't, since I havn't been authenticated by the server yet.

Any way I can make a new request with the Www authentication from the response, without having it inside a in-dialog request??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the second question you've posted in the comment about why the second SUBSCRIBE request is in-dialog (or more correctly in-transaction); it's not.

However because you are re-using the SIP header you got from the response to the first SUBSCRIBE request you will end up with some of the headers set in a way that makes it appear as if it's part of an existing transaction.

The correct way to do it would be to re-use the header from your original SIP request and increment the CSeq and re-generate the CallID. Something along the lines of the code below (note I didn't compile it to check for syntax errors).

```
    static SIPTransport Transport;
    static SIPMessage msg;
    static string inputMsg;
    static SIPUDPChannel channel;
    static SIPRequest subscribeRequest;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeSIP();
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void InitializeSIP()
    {
        //ResolveIPEndPoint
        SIPEndPoint sipep = new SIPEndPoint(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.102.12"), 5060));
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.102.12"), 5060);

        //Set Transport
        Transport = new SIPTransport(SIPDNSManager.ResolveSIPService, new SIPTransactionEngine());

        //IPEndPoint
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.100.10"), 8080);

        //Create Channel object
        channel = new SIPUDPChannel(localEndPoint);
        Transport.AddSIPChannel(channel);

        //Wire transport with incoming requests
        Transport.SIPTransportRequestReceived += new SIPTransportRequestDelegate(Transport_SIPTransportRequestReceived);

        //Wire transport with incoming responses
        Transport.SIPTransportResponseReceived += new SIPTransportResponseDelegate(Transport_SIPTransportResponseReceived);

        inputMsg = "SUBSCRIBE sip:myUSer@192.168.102.12 SIP/2.0" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.100.10:8080;rport;branch=z9hG4bKFBB7EAC06934405182D13950BD51F001" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "From: <sip:subscribeUser@192.168.102.12>;tag=196468136" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "To: <sip:myUser@192.168.102.12>" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "Contact: <sip:subscribeUser@>" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "Call-ID: 1337505490-453410046-705466123" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "CSeq: 1 SUBSCRIBE" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "Max-Forwards: 70" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "Event: Presence" + SIPConstants.CRLF +
        "Content-Length: 0";

        subscribeRequest = SIPRequest.ParseSIPRequest(inputMsg);

        channel.Send(remoteEP, subscribeRequest.ToString());
    }

    static void Transport_SIPTransportResponseReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPResponse sipResponse)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Response method: " + sipResponse.Header.CSeqMethod);
        if(sipResponse.StatusCode == 401 && sipResponse.Header.CSeqMethod == SIPMethodsEnum.SUBSCRIBE)
        {
                            //Resubscribe with Digist
            //SIP Header
            SIPHeader header = subscribeRequest.Header;
            header.CSeq++;
            header.CallID = "some_new_callID";
            header.AuthenticationHeader = sipResponse.Header.AuthenticationHeader;
            header.Expires = 120;

            //New Request
            SIPRequest request = new SIPRequest(SIPMethodsEnum.SUBSCRIBE, new SIPURI(SIPSchemesEnum.sip, remoteEndPoint));
            request.LocalSIPEndPoint = localSIPEndPoint;
            request.RemoteSIPEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
            request.Header = header;

            //Send request
            channel.Send(remoteEndPoint.GetIPEndPoint(), request.ToString());
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error {0} {1}.", sipResponse.StatusCode, sipResponse.Status));
    }

    static void Transport_SIPTransportRequestReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPRequest sipRequest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request body: " + sipRequest.Body);
    }
```

**Update:**

You add credentials to a SIP request as shown in the code below. Note that the authentication header is on a per request basis not a per transport or per channel basis. In the sipsorcery code a SIPTransport can have mutliple SIPChannel's and a SIPChannel can communicate with multiple SIP end points so it would not make sense to set credentials on a transport or channel.

```
SIPAuthorisationDigest authDigest = sipResponse.Header.AuthenticationHeader.SIPDigest;
authDigest.SetCredentials(username, password, uri, SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE.ToString());
authRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader = new SIPAuthenticationHeader(authDigest);
authRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader.SIPDigest.Response = authDigest.Digest;
```

**Update 2:**

The easiest way to send a simple response to a SIP request is as below.

```
static void Transport_SIPTransportRequestReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPRequest sipRequest)
{
    SIPResponse response = SIPTransport.GetResponse(sipRequest, SIPResponseStatusCodesEnum.Ok, null);
    _sipTransport.SendResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: Are there any ways to apply username and password when creating the transport/channel connection to my server??

Comment: A short followup on the previous thread. If I want to send a 200 OK packets after receiving a NOTIFY from my server, would this be the way to do it http://pastebin.com/QQz0gfvt ??

Comment: header.CallId and not header.CallID